# Implement zeromq publisher in django with celery (Broker redis)

Tags: python, django, celery, zeromq, django-celery

i need to implement zmq publisher in django and celery with redis as a broker. But my client doesn't receive anything.

**tasks.py**

```
  from celery import task
  import zmq


  try:
      context = zmq.Context()
      publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
      publisher.bind('tcp://192.168.0.14:9997')
  except:
      pass

  def app_delivery():
      publisher.send("testid : I am a task ")
      return "Passed"
  @task.task(ignore_result=True)
  def add():
      print "I am going to push message "
      return app_delivery()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from notification_core.tasks import add

def resp(request):
    param = request.GET.get('param')
    param = int(param)
    i=0
    while i<param:
        add.delay()
        i+=1
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

**Then running workers using command--**

```
python manage_back.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

**Workers Console Output**

```
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,400: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] I am going to push message
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,400: INFO/MainProcess] Task notification_core.tasks.add[6d44bb48-799e-43dc-af3e-278c0db732c4] succeeded in 0.000511169433594s: 'Passed'
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,575: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: notification_core.tasks.add[8a787b31-5375-4c05-9ddc-2fc66b54ee19]
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,575: WARNING/PoolWorker-3] I am going to push message
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,576: INFO/MainProcess] Task notification_core.tasks.add[8a787b31-5375-4c05-9ddc-2fc66b54ee19] succeeded in 0.000941038131714s: 'Passed'
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,751: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: notification_core.tasks.add[d73ebcdf-9765-43f6-823a-ad03881afa50]
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,752: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] I am going to push message
[2013-04-20 10:37:06,752: INFO/MainProcess] Task notification_core.tasks.add[d73ebcdf-9765-43f6-823a-ad03881afa50] succeeded in 0.000416040420532s: 'Passed'
```

**zmq_client file**

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()

subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect('tcp://192.168.0.14:9997')
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "testid")
while True:
    message = subscriber.recv()
    print "=========="
    print message
    print "=========="
```

i am not getting any output in client, Need some suggestions.

Comment: start by removing the try except pass :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your client first?  Generally you want to start the SUBs before the PUBs.  Also you may find using envelops helpful although it seems like overkill here.

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Pub-Sub-Message-Envelopes

Hope that gives something of us if you aren't simply eating a relevant exception as previously mentioned.